# Why does it prints like this?

Tags: c, function, printf

Why do my output look like this? I want them to be in line, what is the problem?..

```
Id.number    Name            Quantity
1            milk            10     
2            meat            4      
3            egg                 25     
4            yogurt          23     
5            water           30     
6            cake            23     
7            tomatoes            12
```

This is the function to print the stuff

```
 void getPrint(const struct varor reg[], int nrOfGoods){
        int i;
        printf("\nVarunummer \t Namn \t\t\t Lagersaldo\n");
        for(i=0;i<nrOfGoods;i++){
            printf("%d\t\t\t\b\b\b\b\b\b\b%s\t\t\t\t\b\b\b\b\b\b\b%d\n",reg[i].varunummer,reg[i].namn,reg[i].lagersaldo);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And to answer why - probably the 3rd item in array is "egg\t" or alike.

Comment: @xing not fixing the problem